# dompdf slow and produces HTTP request failed error

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf

I am using dompdf with laravel 5 to generate pdf of profile but it take more than 15 minute and then it showing error. the flow is like that open show profile page in browser, page have link to download as pdf with url of same action(show profile) with extra parameter `pdf=yes` and then i use if condition to check pdf call

```
Exception in PDF.php line 219: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 41
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 104
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 110
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 116
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 122
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 128
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 134
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 140
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 145
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 150
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 155
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 160
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 165
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 170
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 177
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 188
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 193
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 211
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 216
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 222
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID personal-info-2 already defined in Entity, line: 227
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag footer invalid in Entity, line: 330
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 333
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 334
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : span in Entity, line: 355
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : span in Entity, line: 358
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/css/bootstrap.min.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
Unable to load css file http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/css/bootstrap.min.css
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
Unable to load css file http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/css/styles.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
Unable to load css file http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/css/styles.css
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/css/custom-style.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
Unable to load css file http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/css/custom-style.css
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/css/custom-mediaqueries.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
Unable to load css file http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/css/custom-mediaqueries.css
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/images/logo.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/images/facebook.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/images/LinkedIn.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/images/Pinterest.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/images/Twitter.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
file_get_contents(http://10.0.0.46:2000/front/images/img-not-found.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

The same page open fine in browser

Comment: can you paste you view used for the generating the pdf and also your controller method .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have PHP notices/warnings/errors set to show to the browser. Regardless of whether dompdf is able to parse your document you won't get the expected output because either:

1. With output buffering *disabled* dompdf will refuse to stream the document because headers have already been sent. This happens because the web server will have already set the content type and sent it to the browser with the PHP errors. If dompdf is unable to change the content type to the PDF MIME type is will refuse to stream the PDF.
2. With output buffering *enabled* dompdf will send the PDF to the browser, but your PHP errors will get cause in the output stream and make the PDF unparsable by PDF viewers.

So, you should disable sending notices to the browser. If not for the reasons above then because it's an information disclosure risk. If you want them enabled you should at least disable them when you're using dompdf (e.g. `ini_set('display_errors', false);`).

That being said, you've got some issues with your document structure: duplicate ID attributes on elements, mismatched open/close tags, unrecognized elements. You should run your generated HTML through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org) and fix as many issues as you can.

Finally, your external resource (CSS, images) are failing to load. Either the URLs are bad or the PHP setting `allow_url_fopen` is set to false.